# How to add different margin to ONE of my li in my ul?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS. I'm practicing by creating a mock portfolio website.

I'm creating a nav bar with the logo in the middle. I want to "vertically center" the logo, if that makes sense. I added a class to that li to try to add margin or padding to the top but it's not working.

I'm working on it on CodePen: http://codepen.io/levane/pen/KdxgmR?editors=110

This is my HTML so far:

```
<body>
    <section id=top>
      <img src="http://creatifydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/photo-1429051883746-afd9d56fbdaf.jpeg" class="bckg-image"/>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Skills</li>
            <li class="logo"><img src="http://creatifydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/icon57.png"/></li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </section>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
body {
  margin: -1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

#top {
  background-color: black;
  height: 53.125em;
}

.bckg-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 53.125em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

nav {
  height: 6.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0em 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Lato, Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

Please let me know if you can spot what I'm doing wrong and feel free to critique anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this CSS

```
.logo{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: .5em
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/PPdxZg?editors=110)